# Hiding body of stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, security, stored-procedures, roles

I defined a role and grant it with only connect to database and execute a specific stored procedure. Users have this role can see the body of procedure when execute this query;

```
select * from  ALL_SOURCE where NAME = 'procedureName';
```

Procedure takes a VARCHAR2 parameter and uses it with a select query. Is that a security issue? Should i hide it somehow or escape the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it would only be a security issue if your procedure was subject to SQL injection.  The fact that you talk about escaping the parameter implies that you may be doing dynamic SQL and may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  If that's the case, you need to fix the procedure, not hide the source.

If your stored procedure is implementing some business logic that you consider proprietary, you could potentially [wrap the code](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/wrap.htm) so that it is obfuscated in the data dictionary.  If you do that, however, make absolutely sure that you your source code in source control because there is no way to unwrap code once you've wrapped it (strictly speaking, there are various techniques that an attacker can use to recover most of the wrapped source if they really wanted to, but it's reasonably secure).